# What SQL Server datatype to use for mixed XML and HL7v2 data?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqldatatypes, hl7, hl7-cda

Consider a column in an MS SQL database which will house either potentially large chunks or XML or pipe-delimited HL7v2 data.

Currently (due to not using forward-thinking) it's currently typed as XML because originally we were only ever accepting XML data. While technically this *could* work, it means that all the XML special characters in the HL7v2 messages are being encoded (`& --> &amp;` etc.).

This is not ideal for what we are doing. If I were to convert this column to a different datatype, what would be recommended? I was thinking `nvarchar(max)` as it seems like it would handle it, but I'm not well-versed in SQL datatypes and the implications of using different types for such data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't much of a choice other than `nvarchar(max)`.

The other options are either `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)`.  You might need Unicode so you can't use `varchar`.  It would work to store it as `varbinary`, but it would just be annoying to work with.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my thoughts weren't that far off then. The only reason I asked is someone here suggested `varbinary(max)` over `nvarchar(max)` but everything I looked into for `varbinary` meant it would mean converting the data to something non-binary just to work with it the way we want to.

Answer (score 1):

Use HAPI to transform the HL7 messages from ER7 (pipe delimited) to [XML encoding](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfmhttp://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=275). That way you can use a single SQL Server XML column for everything. And it will give you the added benefit of being able to query into HL7 message contents using XQuery.

Answer (score -1):

As Nicks say, converting pipe delimited to XML and then persist in XML is the best option, trying to persist xml and pipe delimited values in a same column for me it make no sense, as on source they are different data types.